# Capture few Case fields changes and send to third party

Tags: apex, rest-api, custom-object, asynchronous, change-data-capture

We want to track around 20-30 fields changes of case object. These fields changes can include the long text area field, multiselect picklist values, formula fields, and roll summary also. The reason I mentioned this is because of limitations around field history tracking. So we need some custom solution..

Now what we thought is to :

1. Create a custom object first named "Field Update Object".
2. Write code in case trigger handler saying whenever these specific field values changes, create a "Field Update Object" record. The code will include one text field which will hold combination of : transaction ID + CaseId. Reason of doing this is because unlike case history, I dont want to capture all the changes happening to one field. Ex: If subject of case is changed via user, then from trigger, then changed from flows..What field history will show is 3 records.
3. What i want to have is 1 "Field Update Object" record for 1 field change per case record. Which means if Subject is changed by user > then trigger > then flow, I would like to capture the **Latest value (end value showing to user after transaction is committed)** showing to the user rather than all the values keep getting change from trigger and flows. I will use case insert event to insert a "Field Update Object" record and then case update event if the transaction id + case id combo matches with the existing record..Reason -- It may happen that a trigger can run multiple times synchronously.
4. Then our batch will run after every 5 min to see all the records created in last 5 minutes in "Field Update Object" and create json to send to third party via Rest API.

Also, I think if we are executing a Async job from case trigger which is updating case, this will be a separate transaction, there is no way we can know the if the parent transaction which was a case trigger sync transaction has already created a record or not right?

Another approach could be: CDC and suscribing through trigger which will also dont have event delivery limit applied. But here formula field will not get capture. Similarly for async job also, 2 events of cdc will be fire if we are updating case again.

Really need help on this to have a better design. In Apex we dont have any method to know final values committed to database after multiple same trigger run.